# GIT Development reset with clones

Tags: git, git-reset

My current setup is I have a Prime repo (working directory), Hub repo (bare, developers push and pull from), Clones (for developers). The Prime and Hub repos are kept in sync via various hooks.

There was an issue and I wanted to perform a `reset` to a previous commit on Prime which errored: `To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected`.

This makes sense, but I want to be able to perform resets on Prime if need be.

I want to know what the best method to handle a `reset` to a previous commit in this situation would be.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to force push in your hooks from your prime to the hub and others. This is fine as long as the others are just a mirror of your prime and changes don't travel the other way unless you specifically pull from others into Prime or others can push to it.

Comment: Force pushing into the hub is fine. But the others are used by developers, who will push changes back in aswell... will that be a problem?

Comment: as long as the developers know that changes pushed there can be zapped. Perhaps you need to designate some branches for different purposes. My process (explained here: http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/02/05/branch-per-feature/) relies on resetting.